# Check va_list is array type or not

Tags: c++, c

We have a piece of code that copies one `va_list` to another, the code is implemented as follows:

```
va_list src;
va_list dest;

if(src)
    va_copy(dest, src);
```

The problem is that with all warnings on, I'm getting the following:

> warning: the address of 'src' will always evaluate as 'true'

I know this is because `va_list` is essentially an array and therefore `src` is an address which will always evaluate to true.

Now since `va_list` can also be implemented as a non-array, I don't want to remove this `if` check, because somewhere afterwards it is dereferenced and can lead to a crash. Does this implementation depend on compiler, platform or something else? And can I force it to array?

Comment: Where does your (untrusted) `src` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the conditional. `if (src)` is always invalid (not meaningful) when `src` has type `va_list`. Keeping track of whether a particular `va_list` has been initialized or destroyed yet (via `va_start` or `va_end`) is up to your program logic and cannot be determined by inspection of the `va_list` object in any way. So if there's a possibility it may not have been initialized, you have other bugs to fix...

Comment: `src` in this case has been passed from somewhere else and that is why I need to check whether it is initialised or not, how can I check it via `va_start` and `va_end`?

Comment: @KartikAnand: If there's any question to whether it's initialized, then the caller also needs to pass a flag indicating whether it was initialized, as a separate argument. There is no way to obtain this information by inspecting the `va_list`.

Answer (score 1):

You would only use the `va_copy()` macro with `src` as the source `va_list` if `src` had been properly initialized using `va_start` or `va_copy`.  How a `va_list` is implemented is of no consequence and testing the `va_list` for being `NULL` is meaningless.

Comment: That's what I'm asking, can I check if src has been properly initialised or not?

Answer (score 0):

Per http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_copy - `va_copy` may only be used on an initialised `src` `va_list`.  Afterwards `dest` will be valid.  `dest` should never be "dereferenced" - if you're doing that your usage is broken: you may only use `va_copy`, `va_arg` and `va_end` on it.

Comment: That's what I'm asking, can I check if src has been properly initialised or not?

Comment: No, you can't. Instead keep with it a separate object `int is_initialized;` or similar.

Comment: @KartikAnand: not from looking at the `src` object alone.  As R says, if the code that conditionally initialises `src` is in your control, then you can modify it to set another variable to indicate whether `src` has been initialised.  Of course, if you want to hack you could look at the actual implementations on the systems you need to support and if some non-portable determination is possible, use an `#ifdef` to select it, but that could break with future library updates.

Comment: "src in this case has been passed from somewhere else and that is why I need to check whether it is initialised or not, how can I check it via va_start and va_end?" - that rules out the extra variable.  You have no portable option then, and are unlikely to have any reliable option if the `va_list` variable isn't at least `static`, as the contents of any C-style structure on the stack are indeterminate so there's always potential to mistake garbage values for initialised ones.